# what is '@CalledByNative("...")'?

Tags: java, android, webrtc, webrtc-android

How do I use `@CalledByNative("...")`?  I need a callback from a webrtc lib.

If you know the class PeerConnection on it:

[PeerConnection.java](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/b6760f9e4442410f2bcb6090b3b89bf709e2fce2/webrtc/api/android/java/src/org/webrtc/PeerConnection.java)

Here is a old version of PeerConnection but it's almost same now

I call the function `addStream`, but I can't get the callback from it.

- Please explain how `calledbynative` works!

#### `PeerConnection.java`

```java
/*
 *  Copyright 2013 The WebRTC project authors. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 *  Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license
 *  that can be found in the LICENSE file in the root of the source
 *  tree. An additional intellectual property rights grant can be found
 *  in the file PATENTS.  All contributing project authors may
 *  be found in the AUTHORS file in the root of the source tree.
 */
package org.webrtc;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
/**
 * Java-land version of the PeerConnection APIs; wraps the C++ API
 * http://www.webrtc.org/reference/native-apis, which in turn is inspired by the
 * JS APIs: http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/webrtc.html and
 * http://www.w3.org/TR/mediacapture-streams/
 */
public class PeerConnection {
  static {
    System.loadLibrary("jingle_peerconnection_so");
  }
  /** Tracks PeerConnectionInterface::IceGatheringState */
  public enum IceGatheringState { NEW, GATHERING, COMPLETE }
  /** Tracks PeerConnectionInterface::IceConnectionState */
  public enum IceConnectionState {
    NEW,
    CHECKING,
    CONNECTED,
    COMPLETED,
    FAILED,
    DISCONNECTED,
    CLOSED
  }
  /** Tracks PeerConnectionInterface::SignalingState */
  public enum SignalingState {
    STABLE,
    HAVE_LOCAL_OFFER,
    HAVE_LOCAL_PRANSWER,
    HAVE_REMOTE_OFFER,
    HAVE_REMOTE_PRANSWER,
    CLOSED
  }
  /** Java version of PeerConnectionObserver. */
  public static interface Observer {
    /** Triggered when the SignalingState changes. */
    public void onSignalingChange(SignalingState newState);
    /** Triggered when the IceConnectionState changes. */
    public void onIceConnectionChange(IceConnectionState newState);
    /** Triggered when the ICE connection receiving status changes. */
    public void onIceConnectionReceivingChange(boolean receiving);
    /** Triggered when the IceGatheringState changes. */
    public void onIceGatheringChange(IceGatheringState newState);
    /** Triggered when a new ICE candidate has been found. */
    public void onIceCandidate(IceCandidate candidate);
    /** Triggered when some ICE candidates have been removed. */
    public void onIceCandidatesRemoved(IceCandidate[] candidates);
    /** Triggered when media is received on a new stream from remote peer. */
    public void onAddStream(MediaStream stream);
    /** Triggered when a remote peer close a stream. */
    public void onRemoveStream(MediaStream stream);
    /** Triggered when a remote peer opens a DataChannel. */
    public void onDataChannel(DataChannel dataChannel);
    /** Triggered when renegotiation is necessary. */
    public void onRenegotiationNeeded();
  }
  /** Java version of PeerConnectionInterface.IceServer. */
  public static class IceServer {
    public final String uri;
    public final String username;
    public final String password;
    /** Convenience constructor for STUN servers. */
    public IceServer(String uri) {
      this(uri, "", "");
    }
    public IceServer(String uri, String username, String password) {
      this.uri = uri;
      this.username = username;
      this.password = password;
    }
    public String toString() {
      return uri + "[" + username + ":" + password + "]";
    }
  }
  /** Java version of PeerConnectionInterface.IceTransportsType */
  public enum IceTransportsType { NONE, RELAY, NOHOST, ALL }
  /** Java version of PeerConnectionInterface.BundlePolicy */
  public enum BundlePolicy { BALANCED, MAXBUNDLE, MAXCOMPAT }
  /** Java version of PeerConnectionInterface.RtcpMuxPolicy */
  public enum RtcpMuxPolicy { NEGOTIATE, REQUIRE }
  /** Java version of PeerConnectionInterface.TcpCandidatePolicy */
  public enum TcpCandidatePolicy { ENABLED, DISABLED }
  /** Java version of PeerConnectionInterface.CandidateNetworkPolicy */
  public enum CandidateNetworkPolicy { ALL, LOW_COST }
  /** Java version of rtc::KeyType */
  public enum KeyType { RSA, ECDSA }
  /** Java version of PeerConnectionInterface.ContinualGatheringPolicy */
  public enum ContinualGatheringPolicy { GATHER_ONCE, GATHER_CONTINUALLY }
  /** Java version of PeerConnectionInterface.RTCConfiguration */
  public static class RTCConfiguration {
    public IceTransportsType iceTransportsType;
    public List<IceServer> iceServers;
    public BundlePolicy bundlePolicy;
    public RtcpMuxPolicy rtcpMuxPolicy;
    public TcpCandidatePolicy tcpCandidatePolicy;
    public CandidateNetworkPolicy candidateNetworkPolicy;
    public int audioJitterBufferMaxPackets;
    public boolean audioJitterBufferFastAccelerate;
    public int iceConnectionReceivingTimeout;
    public int iceBackupCandidatePairPingInterval;
    public KeyType keyType;
    public ContinualGatheringPolicy continualGatheringPolicy;
    public int iceCandidatePoolSize;
    public boolean pruneTurnPorts;
    public boolean presumeWritableWhenFullyRelayed;
    public RTCConfiguration(List<IceServer> iceServers) {
      iceTransportsType = IceTransportsType.ALL;
      bundlePolicy = BundlePolicy.BALANCED;
      rtcpMuxPolicy = RtcpMuxPolicy.NEGOTIATE;
      tcpCandidatePolicy = TcpCandidatePolicy.ENABLED;
      candidateNetworkPolicy = candidateNetworkPolicy.ALL;
      this.iceServers = iceServers;
      audioJitterBufferMaxPackets = 50;
      audioJitterBufferFastAccelerate = false;
      iceConnectionReceivingTimeout = -1;
      iceBackupCandidatePairPingInterval = -1;
      keyType = KeyType.ECDSA;
      continualGatheringPolicy = ContinualGatheringPolicy.GATHER_ONCE;
      iceCandidatePoolSize = 0;
      pruneTurnPorts = false;
      presumeWritableWhenFullyRelayed = false;
    }
  };
  private final List<MediaStream> localStreams;
  private final long nativePeerConnection;
  private final long nativeObserver;
  private List<RtpSender> senders;
  private List<RtpReceiver> receivers;
  PeerConnection(long nativePeerConnection, long nativeObserver) {
    this.nativePeerConnection = nativePeerConnection;
    this.nativeObserver = nativeObserver;
    localStreams = new LinkedList<MediaStream>();
    senders = new LinkedList<RtpSender>();
    receivers = new LinkedList<RtpReceiver>();
  }
  // JsepInterface.
  public native SessionDescription getLocalDescription();
  public native SessionDescription getRemoteDescription();
  public native DataChannel createDataChannel(String label, DataChannel.Init init);
  public native void createOffer(SdpObserver observer, MediaConstraints constraints);
  public native void createAnswer(SdpObserver observer, MediaConstraints constraints);
  public native void setLocalDescription(SdpObserver observer, SessionDescription sdp);
  public native void setRemoteDescription(SdpObserver observer, SessionDescription sdp);
  public native boolean setConfiguration(RTCConfiguration config);
  public boolean addIceCandidate(IceCandidate candidate) {
    return nativeAddIceCandidate(candidate.sdpMid, candidate.sdpMLineIndex, candidate.sdp);
  }
  public boolean removeIceCandidates(final IceCandidate[] candidates) {
    return nativeRemoveIceCandidates(candidates);
  }
  public boolean addStream(MediaStream stream) {
    boolean ret = nativeAddLocalStream(stream.nativeStream);
    if (!ret) {
      return false;
    }
    localStreams.add(stream);
    return true;
  }
  public void removeStream(MediaStream stream) {
    nativeRemoveLocalStream(stream.nativeStream);
    localStreams.remove(stream);
  }
  public RtpSender createSender(String kind, String stream_id) {
    RtpSender new_sender = nativeCreateSender(kind, stream_id);
    if (new_sender != null) {
      senders.add(new_sender);
    }
    return new_sender;
  }
  // Note that calling getSenders will dispose of the senders previously
  // returned (and same goes for getReceivers).
  public List<RtpSender> getSenders() {
    for (RtpSender sender : senders) {
      sender.dispose();
    }
    senders = nativeGetSenders();
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(senders);
  }
  public List<RtpReceiver> getReceivers() {
    for (RtpReceiver receiver : receivers) {
      receiver.dispose();
    }
    receivers = nativeGetReceivers();
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(receivers);
  }
  public boolean getStats(StatsObserver observer, MediaStreamTrack track) {
    return nativeGetStats(observer, (track == null) ? 0 : track.nativeTrack);
  }
  // Starts recording an RTC event log. Ownership of the file is transfered to
  // the native code. If an RTC event log is already being recorded, it will be
  // stopped and a new one will start using the provided file. Logging will
  // continue until the stopRtcEventLog function is called. The max_size_bytes
  // argument is ignored, it is added for future use.
  public boolean startRtcEventLog(int file_descriptor, int max_size_bytes) {
    return nativeStartRtcEventLog(file_descriptor, max_size_bytes);
  }
  // Stops recording an RTC event log. If no RTC event log is currently being
  // recorded, this call will have no effect.
  public void stopRtcEventLog() {
    nativeStopRtcEventLog();
  }
  // TODO(fischman): add support for DTMF-related methods once that API
  // stabilizes.
  public native SignalingState signalingState();
  public native IceConnectionState iceConnectionState();
  public native IceGatheringState iceGatheringState();
  public native void close();
  public void dispose() {
    close();
    for (MediaStream stream : localStreams) {
      nativeRemoveLocalStream(stream.nativeStream);
      stream.dispose();
    }
    localStreams.clear();
    for (RtpSender sender : senders) {
      sender.dispose();
    }
    senders.clear();
    for (RtpReceiver receiver : receivers) {
      receiver.dispose();
    }
    receivers.clear();
    freePeerConnection(nativePeerConnection);
    freeObserver(nativeObserver);
  }
  private static native void freePeerConnection(long nativePeerConnection);
  private static native void freeObserver(long nativeObserver);
  private native boolean nativeAddIceCandidate(
      String sdpMid, int sdpMLineIndex, String iceCandidateSdp);
  private native boolean nativeRemoveIceCandidates(final IceCandidate[] candidates);
  private native boolean nativeAddLocalStream(long nativeStream);
  private native void nativeRemoveLocalStream(long nativeStream);
  private native boolean nativeGetStats(StatsObserver observer, long nativeTrack);
  private native RtpSender nativeCreateSender(String kind, String stream_id);
  private native List<RtpSender> nativeGetSenders();
  private native List<RtpReceiver> nativeGetReceivers();
  private native boolean nativeStartRtcEventLog(int file_descriptor, int max_size_bytes);
  private native void nativeStopRtcEventLog();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

@CallByNative is an `annotation` used by the Google WebRtc Development team to specify mappings between Java and Native (`C/C++`) Stacks of WebRtc.

As said on there official WebRtc Chromium Git representation such as:

> @CalledByNative is used by the JNI generator to create the necessary
>   JNI  bindings and expose this method to native code.

Now if there is a question that how is it happening? How WebRtc Java code is inter-linked with WebRtc Native Code?

For this, I will suggest looking into the Native Code of WebRtc will help you most. You will learn more informative and relevant stuff from the `Comments` inside the native stack. On the other hand, you should also have the basic knowledge of

- How *Java Native Interface* (JNI) works
- How WebRtc Java and Native Stack is interrelated

To get detailed intuition of Java Native Interface, you can visit these references:

- [Java Native Interface Specification Contents](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html)
- [Java Native Interface Tips](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni)

Here I am giving you an example from `PeerConnection.java`. Let's say, we have a method inside `PeerConnection.java` class such as:

```
@CalledByNative("IceGatheringState")
static IceGatheringState fromNativeIndex(int nativeIndex) {
  return values()[nativeIndex];
}
```

Now this method is mapped inside `src/sdk/android/src/jni/pc/peer_connection.cc` class such as:

```
static ScopedJavaLocalRef<jobject> JNI_PeerConnection_IceGatheringState(
    JNIEnv* env,
    const JavaParamRef<jobject>& j_pc) {
  return Java_IceGatheringState_fromNativeIndex(
      env, ExtractNativePC(env, j_pc)->ice_gathering_state());
}
```

If you follow the same technique by looking into both Java and Native Class of `PeerConnection`, you must found some other linkages of that kind. Now, what @CallByNative did here?

If you look, after loading library, @CallByNative basically do these two things such as:

- Tells which inner class the method belongs to
- Expose this Java method to the Native Code
- Make JNI Bindings with Java and Native Code

These types of annotations are provided by Google Developers to make JNI easy and understandable while working with [Pre-built libraries](https://bintray.com/google/webrtc/google-webrtc) or your own compiled libraries such as `libwebrtc.aar`.

Answer (score 3):

I did some investigation on this topic lately and I would like to share my results. I realized that it might have to do something with `@Override` methods and the "super" keyword in Java. I suppose when we try to call e.g. the override method `onIceCandidate` or `onAddStream`, which is located in the [PeerConnection.java](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/b6760f9e4442410f2bcb6090b3b89bf709e2fce2/webrtc/api/android/java/src/org/webrtc/PeerConnection.java) file, from the [MainActivity.java](https://github.com/vivek1794/webrtc-android-codelab/blob/master/Step-3/app/src/main/java/xyz/vivekc/webrtccodelab/MainActivity.java) class we write:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, SignallingClient.SignalingInterface {
...
private void createPeerConnection() {
...
            @Override
            public void onIceCandidate(IceCandidate iceCandidate) {
                super.onIceCandidate(iceCandidate);
                onIceCandidateReceived(iceCandidate);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAddStream(MediaStream mediaStream) {
                showToast("Received Remote stream");
                super.onAddStream(mediaStream);
                gotRemoteStream(mediaStream);
            }
...
}
...
}
```

Furthermore, the `onAddStream` and `onIceCandidate` are both override methods. If we trace those methods back by the help of the `super` keyword we get into the following file [CustomPeerConnectionObserver.java](https://github.com/vivek1794/webrtc-android-codelab/blob/master/Step-3/app/src/main/java/xyz/vivekc/webrtccodelab/CustomPeerConnectionObserver.java):

```java
class CustomPeerConnectionObserver implements PeerConnection.Observer {
...
    @Override
    public void onIceCandidate(IceCandidate iceCandidate) {
        Log.d(logTag, "onIceCandidate() called with: iceCandidate = [" + iceCandidate + "]");
    }
...
    @Override
    public void onAddStream(MediaStream mediaStream) {
        Log.d(logTag, "onAddStream() called with: mediaStream = [" + mediaStream + "]");
    }
...
}
```

At this point when we take a look at the class we see that it "implements" the `PeerConnection.Observer`. If we keep investigating a bit further, we realize that we are guided to our file [PeerConnection.java](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/b6760f9e4442410f2bcb6090b3b89bf709e2fce2/webrtc/api/android/java/src/org/webrtc/PeerConnection.java):

```java
public class PeerConnection {
...
public interface Observer {
...
        @CalledByNative("Observer")
        void onIceCandidate(IceCandidate var1);
...
        @CalledByNative("Observer")
        void onAddStream(MediaStream var1);
...
 }
...
}
```

We get into the "interface" called Observer. So far I took the example from [GitHub](https://github.com/vivek1794/webrtc-android-codelab) and I tried to comprehend how the application works. It is for Android, but I suppose we use Java, so there should not be a huge difference, correct me if I am wrong.

In conclusion, I suppose it somehow gets called automatically when a special event occurs and/or when it is mentioned/written as a `@Override` method, where we need it to be called. I also assume that the `@CalledByNative` tag could have impact on the method calls, i.e. `addStream`, also respectively in the example I provided above:

- onIceCandidate
- onAddStream.

I hope I was able to at least give you some reference points about my investigation on this behaviour, where you could pick up the trace and make further research. I am also looking forward that an expert could answer this good question on how `@CalledByNative` works.

Comment: There are some more details available [here](https://github.com/adobe/chromium/blob/master/base/android/java/org/chromium/base/CalledByNative.java). `CalledByNative` is documented as "// This annotation is used by the JNI generator to create the necessary JNI
// bindings and expose this method to native code."